# Loading\Querying large Serialized objects

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, memory

I have a serialized class of 30MB stored externally which contains lookup values. Each time a webservice request is received, I need to load the serialized file to memory and do a lookup for a specific key against this serialized class. This operation is time consuming as well as resource intensive, which badly affects the application performance.

Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you should move your Serialized contents to a Database, that will be more efficient.

Comment: The problem is that, the client will be providing us lookup values in  serialized format only. Even after deployment, any updates to the lookup vales are made by replacing existing serialized file with new one.

Comment: Even then you can create an data base layer which will do the mapping and comparison between client recived data and you data in data base. I recive database from facebook in JSON.. but i keep tham in MSSQL.. i had code to do the work between both..

Comment: Okay as you mentioned, I will try with loading values to database.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the Lookup values in the serialized class to Application object. Before this the values in the serialized class need to be loaded to System.Collections.Generic.HashSet

Also don't forget to override the hashcode function. For added performance, pregenerate your hashcode in your constructor.

Comment: I will look into this once I am done with the database suggestion mentioned by Shekar. Thx